# How to reset a jquery animation and start over

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm making a simple javascript game where you click the ball, it goes up, and you have to click it again before it touches the ground. How do I make it so that you click the ball on the way down and it stop the last request and begin moving back up again?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    function moveBall() {
        $.fx.speeds._default = 3000;
        $("#ball").animate({bottom:'360px'});
        $("#ball").animate({bottom:'0px'});
        setTimeout( function(){
            document.getElementById("block").innerHTML = "Game Over";
        }, 6000 );
    }
    </script> 

    <style>
        #ballGame {
            height:350px;
            width:350px;
            border-style:solid; 
            border-width:5px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #ball {
            background:#98bf21;
            height:50px;
            width:50px;
            position:relative;
            border-radius:100px;
            outline:0;
        }
        #block {
            height:300px;
        }
</style>

<div id="ballGame">
    <center>
        <div id="block"></div>
        <button id="ball" onclick="moveBall()"></button>
    </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#ball").stop(true, false)` at the beginning of your `moveBall` function.

See the jQuery doc : http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, I would clean up the code a little first; you don't need to call a function (`onclick="moveBall()"`) within the HTML code. Instead, just create a click-function:

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    $('#ball').stop(true);
    $("#ball").animate({bottom:'360px'});
    $("#ball").animate({bottom:'0px'}, function() {
        $('#block').text("Game Over");
    });
}
```

I also changed the part where it shows the text "Game Over", so that it only appears when the animation that brings the ball down is complete.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/a71xf13k/

Comment: Thanks, not a school project, but I was stuck on the "game over" delay too. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! (And sorry for the comment; I removed it from my answer...)